# Linux C compiler: cannot execute cc1

Tags: linux, conda

I am trying to run `cmake` for some software in Linux and when I do, I get the following error:

`x86_64-conda-linux-gnu-cc: fatal error: cannot execute 'cc1': execvp: No such file or directory`

The `x86_64-conda-linux-gnu-cc` exists, and I did not see any errors when I had installed it in conda, so I'm not sure why I am getting this error message.

This is the full error message:

```
-- Check for working C compiler: /home1/lzzard/Conda/Miniconda3/envs/libra/bin/x86_64-conda-linux-gnu-cc - broken
CMake Error at /home1/lzzard/Conda/Miniconda3/envs/libra/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:69 (message):
  The C compiler

    "/home1/lzzard/Conda/Miniconda3/envs/libra/bin/x86_64-conda-linux-gnu-cc"

  is not able to compile a simple test program.

  It fails with the following output:

    Change Dir: /home1/lzzard/libra/_build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp
    
    Run Build Command(s):/usr/bin/gmake -f Makefile cmTC_17fa6/fast && /usr/bin/gmake  -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_17fa6.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_17fa6.dir/build
    gmake[1]: Entering directory `/home1/lzzard/libra/_build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
    Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_17fa6.dir/testCCompiler.c.o
    /home1/lzzard/Conda/Miniconda3/envs/libra/bin/x86_64-conda-linux-gnu-cc   -march=nocona -mtune=haswell -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fstack-protector-strong -fno-plt -O2 -ffunction-sections -pipe -isystem /home1/lzzard/Conda/Miniconda3/envs/libra/include  -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_17fa6.dir/testCCompiler.c.o -c /home1/lzzard/libra/_build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/testCCompiler.c
    x86_64-conda-linux-gnu-cc: fatal error: cannot execute 'cc1': execvp: No such file or directory
    compilation terminated.
    gmake[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/cmTC_17fa6.dir/testCCompiler.c.o] Error 1
    gmake[1]: Leaving directory `/home1/lzzard/libra/_build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
    gmake: *** [cmTC_17fa6/fast] Error 2
    
    

  

  CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:14 (PROJECT)
```

Comment: Try to compile a simple C program (eg `hello-world.c`) with `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g -v hello-world.c -o hello`

Comment: The simple program works

Comment: Then why can't you use the `gcc` (not the conda one) in your distribution? Please edit your question to explain more. Or try installing [Debian](https://debian.org/)

Comment: Consider also using [strace](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) on the command line to understand what is happening on your Linux computer.